# How to examine a relationship between two variables, factored by a third?

Tags: r, relationship

I need to examine the relationship between one variable (cumulative.cat which is reported as 0 and 1) and another variable (ability, which is reported as "likely" and "unlikely"), but factored out by a third variable (major.airport, which is reported as 0 and 1). I have a very basic understanding on R.

What I have tried so far is:

```
table(data.frame$cumulative.cat,data$frame$ability)
```

but that doesn't break it down by major.airport. I feel like there should be some way to use the table or prop.table fuction to find the relationship by each category of the major.airport variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xtabs`

```r
xtabs( ~ cumulative.cat + ability + major.airport, data = data.frame)
#> , , major.airport = 0
#> 
#>               ability
#> cumulative.cat likely unlikely
#>              0     12       12
#>              1     10       10
#> 
#> , , major.airport = 1
#> 
#>               ability
#> cumulative.cat likely unlikely
#>              0     13       12
#>              1     18       13
```

---

**Data used**

The following made-up data set matches the description of the data given in the question. Note that it's bad practice to call your data frame `data.frame`:

```r
set.seed(1)

data.frame <- data.frame(
  cumulative.cat = sample(0:1, 100, TRUE),
  ability = sample(c('likely', 'unlikely'), 100, TRUE),
  major.airport = sample(0:1, 100, TRUE))

head(data.frame)
#>   cumulative.cat  ability major.airport
#> 1              0 unlikely             1
#> 2              1 unlikely             1
#> 3              0 unlikely             0
#> 4              0   likely             1
#> 5              1   likely             1
#> 6              0   likely             1
```